# How do I configure sound devices in Skype 4.2 on 12.04 x64?

Tags: 12.04, sound, skype, microphone

I got a new PC and installed the 64-bit version of Ubuntu 12.04 to utilize all of the 8GB of RAM and the APU to the max. So far everything works except sound in Skype 4.2.

[image: Screenshot of the settings window.]

I can't snap the whole list of devices offered because both ScreenCloud and Ubuntu's screenshotter refuse to snap when the list is active, but I intentionally used different entries for the speakers and ringing devices. The others offered are on the same basis, all "digital" (unlike the analog choice I have for the microphone which I am pretty sure would work). It's a Realtek HD sound card, integrated, pretty common on today's MoBos.

Anyone has a clue about what could be wrong? I'm pretty sure the Skype login sound was there two days ago, it's since this morning I noticed that it's gone.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this problem 5 days ago after reinstalling Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit. 
The problem is the fact that Skype is a multi-arch program, so if I’m not wrong it uses a mix of 32 bit and 64 bit libraries. 
To solve the sound issue I just installed libpulse0:i386 package

```
sudo apt-get install libpulse0:i386
```

then reboot, and pulse-audio showed up in audio settings in skype.

Comment: thanks, @user155897, youe advice worked like a charm: I installed the i386 lib, rebooted, and pulseaudio appeared in Skype's sound settings. Sound works now for me.